# event succes не работает при выполнении ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Задача до боли тривиальная, однако в ступоре уже несколько часов. В общем отправляю ajax запрос на сервер, удаляя товар из корзины. Серверная часть работает. Товар удаляется из корзины. Однако ивент succes никак не хочет работать. 
В консоли ошибок нет - 200. Видно что пришел ответ в виде пустого json объекта.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete-item").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        var data = {}
        var product_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        data["product_id"] = product_id

        $.ajax({ 
            url: $(this).attr("href"),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            succes: function () {
                console.log('worked')

            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Error')
            }
          });


    });
});
```

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_item(request):
cart = Cart(request)
print(cart.items_list, 'cart from session')

if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    print('View started ajax')
    product_id = request.POST['product_id']
    cart.delete_item(product_id)
    return_object = {}
    return JsonResponse(return_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

В слове *success* не хватало **s**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete-item").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var data = {}
    var product_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    data["product_id"] = product_id
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { // Here success :)
        console.log('worked', data)

      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log('Error', data)
      }
    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="delete-item" data-id="Some_id2829" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts">This is it</a>
```

Comment: Я думал конечно что упустил какую то мелочь, но чтобы такую(( Благодарю за ответ!